# Calendar View to Hide 12:00 AM

Tags: 2007, javascript, sharepoint-calendar

Dealing with SharePoint 2007 Calendar view.
We are trying some javascript via a content editor to hide the "12:00 AM" when viewing the data from a calendar view.

It's only hiding the first instance...all other strings of "12:00 AM" are still showing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var el = document.getElementById('MontlyViewDefault_CalendarView');
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace("12:00 AM", "");
</script>
```

Trying this too, but no luck as well:

```
var el = document.getElementById('MontlyViewDefault_CalendarView');

for(var i=0; i < el.length; i++) {
      el[i].innerHTML = el[i].innerHTML.replace("12:00 AM","");
    }
```

---

Got it with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i=0; i < el.length; i++) {
      el[i].innerHTML = el[i].innerHTML.replace("12:00 AM","");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: getElementById is only going to return the first instance, you need a different selector to get all items

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i=0; i < el.length; i++) {
      el[i].innerHTML = el[i].innerHTML.replace("12:00 AM","");
    }
</script>
```